# What is the colour scheme used for the poetry terminal images and how can I use it?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

The terminal windows for the poetry python package has a very nice dark colour scheme.

See images on the package page:

https://python-poetry.org/

Is this a standard colour scheme for unix/linux systems? If so, how can I set this up?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!